# Why byte is printed in different sizes as bit array

Tags: java, bit-manipulation

I wanted to print my byte in bit string form. I found the way to do it

```
String s = String.format("%8s", Integer.toBinaryString(headerArr[bytenumber])).replace(' ', '0');

System.out.println(s);
```

But I get super weird outputs:

```
11111111111111111111111111111111
00001111
11111111111111111111111111111110
00000111
11111111111111111111111111111100
00000011
11111111111111111111111111111000
00000001
11111111111111111111111111110000
11111111111111111111111111111111
11111111111111111111111111100000
01111111
11111111111111111111111111000000
00111111
11111111111111111111111110000000
00011111
00001111
00001110
00000110
00000100
```

How can I possibly receive different bit string representations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The doc of `Integer.toBinaryString` states

> The unsigned integer value is the argument plus 2^32 if the argument is
>   negative

Use instead

```
Integer.toBinaryString(headerArr[bytenumber] & 0xff);
```

The `String.format("%8s", s)` does never shorten the string `s`. It only prepends spaces if `s` has less than 8 characters.